# Javascript AJAX Call to PHP Function for File Download

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script that is fetching data from a database via an AJAX call. It is then passing it to a PHP method that scrubs and manipulates a bunch of the data.

After the data has been updated, I am trying to fire a save dialog so that the user can download the generated excel file.

From what I have read, it might not be possible to trigger that from an AJAX call. Others have recommended passing the link to the file to open it in a new window for the download... however, the file is created dynamically via `fput` so there isn't actually a file I can reference.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (!isset($_POST['function'])) {
    $aResult['error'] = 'No function name!';
}

if (!isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $aResult['error'] = 'No data!';
}

if (!isset($aResult['error'])) {
    switch ($_POST['function']) {
        case 'map':
            $aResult = mapFields($_POST['data']);
            break;
        case 'export':
            export($_POST['data']);
            break;
    }
}

echo json_encode($aResult);

// Given a JSON string, convert the key names to the field names
function mapFields($arr)
{

    // Vars
    $map = array_column($arr['x']['columnDefs']['z'], 'caption', 'field');

    // Columns we don't include in the output
    $exclude = array(
        'q', // Identifier QID
        'n', // Identifier NTID
    );

    // Columns we want to ignore the mapping for
    $ignore = array(
        'Notes', // Notes
    );

    // Loop over our notes and include them in our array
    if (isset($arr['x']['notes'])) {
        foreach ($arr['x']['notes']['n'] as $key => $val) {
            foreach ($arr['x']['results']['d'] as $rKey => $rVal) {
                if ($val['QID'] == $rVal['q']) {
                    $arr['x']['results']['d'][$rKey]['Notes'] = $val['Notes'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Loop over the results and replace our key id with the name from the mapping
    foreach ($arr['x']['results']['d'] as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            // Are there any fields we should omit?
            if (!in_array($k, $exclude)) {
                // Are there any fields we should leave alone?
                if (in_array($k, $ignore)) {
                    $result[$key][$k] = $v;
                } else {
                    // Mapped fields
                    $result[$key][$map[$k]] = $v;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

// Export our file as csv data
function export($results)
{

    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    $fileName = 'Data_Export_(' . count($results) . '_Results).csv';

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Pragma: public");

    $fh = @fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // Flags
    $headerDisplayed = false;

    // Loop over the results
    foreach ($results as $data) {

        // Add a header row if it hasn't been added yet
        if (!$headerDisplayed) {
            // Use the keys from $data as the titles
            fputcsv($fh, array_keys($data));
            $headerDisplayed = true;
        }

        // Put the data into the stream
        fputcsv($fh, $data);
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose($fh);
    ob_end_flush();

    // Make sure nothing else is sent, our file is done
    exit;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function mapFields() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/php/functions.php",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            function: 'map',
            data: tempData
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "includes/php/functions.php",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    function: 'export',
                    data: data
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    // Export

                }

            });

        }

    });
}
```

Any other approach I can take to this so that I can allow the user to download this dynamic excel file?

Comment: You may want to look at this question, where they found a solution for themselves: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983122/how-to-do-a-form-post-that-downloads-a-file

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/175